# Expand \def in \write18

Tags: expansion, shell-escape, definition

I have defined the following command:

```
\newcommand{\formatcommand}[1]{
    \def\temp{#1}
    \def\s{\ifx\temp\empty empty\else not empty\fi}
    echo "\s"
}
```

This works correctly:

```
\formatcommand{}
\formatcommand{ }
```

[image: sample]

However, when using the above command inside `\write18`,

```
\immediate\write18{\formatcommand{}}
```

the `\def`s seem to not be expanding, since I'm getting `\def is not an executable...`, meaning that `\write18` sent the body of `\formatcommand{}` without expanding it to the command line. How can this be fixed?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\formatcommand}[1]{
    \def\temp{#1}
    \def\s{\ifx\temp\empty empty\else not empty\fi}
    echo "\s"
}

\formatcommand{}
\formatcommand{ }

\immediate\write18{\formatcommand{}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When TeX writes the contents of a `\write` command, it expands all material similarly to what happens on an `\edef` defintion, i.e. all expandable commands are expanded but no execution happens. Macro definitions (or other assignments) are not expandable, so the `\def`s remain in the input stream when they are written as shell commands.

The solution is to use a fully-expandable test for an empty token list, like the following `\ifempty` macro:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifempty[1]{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\formatcommand}[1]{
    echo "\ifempty{#1}{empty}{not empty}"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally I recommend siracusa'a solution, but if you LuaTeX there is another trick which you can use if your problem can't be written in an expandable manner:

LuaTeX has primitives `\immediateassignment` and `\immediateassigned` which allow expandable `\def`s:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\formatcommand}[1]{
    \immediateassignment\def\temp{#1}
    \immediateassignment\def\s{\ifx\temp\empty empty\else not empty\fi}
    echo "\s"
}

\formatcommand{}
\formatcommand{ }

\immediate\write255{\formatcommand{}}

\end{document}
```

(I replaced `\write18` with `\write255` to show the command on the terminal because shell-escape works differently in LuaTeX, so executing the command would have needed bigger changes.)

Using `\immediateassigned`, you can make all assignments in a block expandable:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\formatcommand}[1]{
  \immediateassigned{%
    \def\temp{#1}
    \def\s{\ifx\temp\empty empty\else not empty\fi}
  }%
    echo "\s"
}

\formatcommand{}
\formatcommand{ }

\immediate\write255{\formatcommand{}}

\end{document}
```